# How to nest rules in HP Exstream?

Tags: formatting, rule-engine, hp-exstream

I am using HP Exstream (formerly Dialogue from Exstream Software) version 5.0.x.  It has a feature to define and save boolean expressions as "Rules".

It has been about 6 years since I used this, but does anybody know if you can define a rule in terms of another rule?  There is a "VB-like" language in a popup window, so you are not *forced* to use the and/or, variable-relational expression form, but I don't have documentation handy.  :-(

I would like to define a rule, "NotFoo", in terms of "Foo", instead of repeating the inverse of the whole thing.  (Yes, that would be retarded, but that's probably what I will be forced to do, as in other examples of what I am maintaining.)  Actually, nested rules would have many uses, if I can figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Sarah.  I lack sufficient mojo to create new tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found that what one needs to do in this case is create user defined "functions", which can reference each other (so long as you avoid indirect recursion).  Then, use the functions to define the "rules" (and, don't even bother with "library" rules instead of "inline" rules, most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the question but since you had to answer yourself there is a better way to handle it.

The issue with using functions and testing the result is that there's a good chance that you're going to be adding unnecessary processing because the engine will run through the function every time it's called.  Not a big issue with a simple function but it can easily become a problem if the function is complex, especially if it's called in several places.

Depending on the timing of the function (you didn't say whether it was a run level, customer level, or specific to particular documents), it's often better to have the function set a User Boolean variable to store the result then in your library rules you can just check the value of the variable without having to run through the function every time.

Comment: Thanks!  And thank God I don't have to use Exstream any more :-)  I glad I don't have to find out how to ensure that the variable is set before the thing referencing it runs :-(